# Efficient and simple comparison operators for structs

Tags: c++

The application I am working on currently has a large number structs which contain data which is input from various sources such as data bases and files. For example like this:

```
struct A 
{
    float val1;
    std::string val2;
    int val3;

    bool operator < (const A& other) const;
};
```

For processing, these structs are stored up in STL-containers, such as maps and therefore need a comparison operator. These are all the same and using simple boolean logic they can be written like this:

```
bool A:operator < (const A& o) const {
    return val1 < o.val1 || 
        (val1 == o.val1 && ( val2 < o.val2 || 
            (val2 == o.val2 && ( val3 < o.val3 ) ) );
}
```

This seems efficient, but has several drawbacks:

1. These expressions get huge if the structs as a dozen or more members.
2. It is cumbersome to write and maintain if members change.
3. It needs to be done for every struct separately.

Is there a more maintainable way to compare structs like this?

Comment: This is a very use-case dependent scenario. Not all structures need to compare all members in their comparison operator. And not all structures needs to have comparison operators (just storing in a vector, for example, doesn't need any comparison).

Comment: It's not best practise to make operator< a member function, it should be a free function. This ensures that C++ applies the same type conversion rules to both sides of an expression using `<`.

Comment: Consider using `tuple`s over `struct`s, it includes a comparison operator with that meaning.

Comment: (There are no structs in C++, `struct` declares a class)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the builtin comparison that ships with `<tuple>` like this:

```
#include <tuple>

bool A::operator < (const A& rhs) const {
    return std::tie(val1, val2, val3) < std::tie(rhs.val1, rhs.val2, rhs.val3);
}
```

This doesn't scale when more and more data members are added to the struct, but this might also be a hint that you could create intermediate structs that implement `operator <` and hence play well with the above implementation of a top-level `operator <`.

Let me add three additional comments on `operator <`.

1. Once you have `operator <`, clients will expect that all other comparison operators are provided, too. Before we have the three-way comparison in C++20, you can avoid unnecessary boilerplate code by e.g. using the Boost operator library:

   ```
   #include <boost/operators.hpp>

   struct A : private boost::totally_ordered<A> { /* ... */ };
   ```

   which generates all operators based on `operator <` and `operator ==` for you.
2. In your example, there is no need for the operator to be a member of `A`. You can make it a free function, which is preferable (see [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) for the rationale).
3. If there is no intrinsic ordering related to `A` and you just need `operator <` to store instances as keys in a `std::map`, consider providing a named predicate.

Comment: All this boiler-plate really emphasizes how much of a boon `auto operator<=>(const A&) = default;` is going to be.

Answer (score 9):

Great answer by lubgr.

One further refinement I perform is the creation of a member function `as_tuple` on any object which is to be ordered by its members:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    float val1;
    std::string val2;
    int val3;

    // provide easy conversion to tuple
    auto as_tuple() const
    {
        return std::tie(val1, val2, val3);
    }
};
```

Which often gives rise to thoughts of a general system of making objects and tuples interchangeable in terms of comparisons

```
template<class T> auto as_tuple(T&& l) -> decltype(l.as_tuple()) 
{
    return l.as_tuple();
}

template<class...Ts> 
auto as_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...> const& tup) 
-> decltype(auto)
{
    return tup;
}

template<class L, class R>
auto operator < (L const& l, R const& r)
-> decltype(as_tuple(l), void(), as_tuple(r), void(), bool())
{
    return as_tuple(l) < as_tuple(r);
}
```

Which allows such code as:

```
int main()
{
    auto a = A { 1.1, "foo", 0 };
    auto b = A { 1.1, "foo", 1 };

    auto test1 = a < b;
    std::cout << test1 << std::endl;

    auto test2 = a < std::make_tuple(1.1, "bar", 0);
    std::cout << test2 << std::endl;

    auto test3 = std::make_tuple(1.0, "bar", 0) < std::make_tuple(1.1, "bar", 0);
    std::cout << test3 << std::endl;

    auto test4 = a < std::make_tuple(2l, std::string("bar"), 0);
    std::cout << test4 << std::endl;

}
```

example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ead750f3f65e3ee9

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that there are several comma operators in that `decltype`? Is their purpose to SFINAE (and if so, what does the `void()` accomplish)?

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes their purpose is SFINAE. The void() acts as a separator which eliminates a very unlikely corner case. Imagine if as_tuple(R) returned a type for which a comma (,) operator had been defined. This would change the meaning of the expression in the decltype.

Comment: @RichardHodges - Isn't that a concern for `as_tuple(l)` too?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes you're right. I had the same thought after the question was posed. I'll update it.